# Passenger and Rails on Scalr.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, passenger, mod-rails

I'm having an issue with Passenger and Rails working together on my Scalr application server.

I have Rails 2.3.5 installed and Passenger 2.2.7. I am running ruby 1.8.6 (patchlevel 111). Previous version of both Rails and Passenger worked fine together but now I get shown just a file tree and no application after updating:

http://matchmefor.com/

Does anyone have any ideas what I might have done wrong? Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Can you also post the error stack? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a problem in your apache config file - can you show the relevant section for your site setup from your httpd.conf file?